How to connect iPhone to Macmini server and operate it using idb commands?
We are trying to integrate physical iphone with backend server in a way that for any event or action for example, we are able to complete the operation with just our apis for each event and it gets reflected on actual physical iphone. Operations can be click , drag, install app, screenshot , recording etc .
Example - I hit takescreenshot api it should be able to take screenshot of the physical iphone and return it.
Tried connecting th iPhone device to Macmini but it is not comming up fully.
Looking for detailed stepsto connect iPhone to Macmini server and operate on it using idb commands
